# Javascript array search filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, multipleselection

I have the scenario, with provided example JSON data:

```
[{
   "name": "Joe",
   "age": "28",
   "hobby": ["Reading", "Chilling", "Cycling"]
},
{
   "name": "Beck",
   "age": "25",
   "hobby": ["Drinking", "Cycling"]
},
{
   "name": "Candace",
   "age": "24",
   "hobby": ["Reading", "Singing"]
}]
```

Let's say the array above are shown in some list in web page.

I have 2 (two) search dropdown with multiple selection to search name and age.

- For name, let's say it shows all distinct hobbies (Reading, Chilling, Cycling, Drinking, Singing).
- For age, let's say it have 2 options for age range: 23-26 and > 27.

For searching hobby, my code is (in ReactJS):

```
filteredPersons = this.state.personList.filter( person =>{
  return person.hobby.some(v=> filterHobby.indexOf(v) !== -1)
});
```

which is:

- `personList` is list of array from JSON above;
- `filterHobby` is list of array from multiple select, ex: if `filterHobby = ["Reading","Singing"]`, it will show Joe and Candace.

The question is, how can I search for age with multiple selection?

Expected result:

- Choose `23-26` **only** will show Beck and Candace
- Choose `>27` **only** will show Joe
- Choose both will show Beck, Candace and Joe

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: In a first step map the selected age range to an appropriate filter function (I'd suggest not doing magic here, a simple switch or similar... [readability; can be extracted/*magic-ified* later if it gets too complex]), then apply that filter function similar to what you do with `filterHobby`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with all filters and another for keeping function for getting the ages of the objects.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Joe", age: "28", hobby: ["Reading", "Chilling", "Cycling"] }, { name: "Beck", age: "25", hobby: ["Drinking", "Cycling"] }, { name: "Candace", age: "24", hobby: ["Reading", "Singing"] }],
    functions = {
        '23-26': ({ age }) => age >= 23 && age <= 26,
        '>27': ({ age }) => age > 27
    },
    filters = {
        hobby:  ["Reading", "Cycling"],                
        age: ['23-26']
    },
    result = data.filter(o =>  
        filters.hobby.some(v => o.hobby.includes(v)) &&
        filters.age.some(fn => functions[fn](o))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `filter` function for **filtering** an array.

We have an array with persons:

```
const persons = [
    {
       "name": "Joe",
       "age": "28",
       "hobby": ["Reading", "Chilling", "Cycling"]
    },
    {
       "name": "Beck",
       "age": "25",
       "hobby": ["Drinking", "Cycling"]
    },
    {
       "name": "Candace",
       "age": "24",
       "hobby": ["Reading", "Singing"]
    }
]
```

And then we will filter that array:

```
persons.filter((person) => {
    return person.age > 27;
})
```

This code returns us **Joe**'s info:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": "28",
    "hobby": ["Reading", "Chilling", "Cycling"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ageFilters = ['23-26','>27']
selectedFilter = '23-26';

filteredPersons = this.state.persons.filter(({age}) => {
 const _age = parseInt(age);
 if(selectedFilter === '23-26') {             // "23-26"
  return (_age>=23) && (_age<=26);
 } else if(selectedFilter === '>27') {                          // "27"
  return (_age>27);
 } else {
  return true;
 }
})
```

Comment: my dropdown value will be single array (like `filterHobby` described above) and i actually confused the value for each option. maybe like: `filterAge = ["23-26", ">27"]` (?)

Comment: in that array one value will be selected by the user right? use that as the condition for checking.

Comment: sorry, single array with multiple value, the `selectedFilter` can be multiple.

Comment: Okay, in that case, you can use nina's solution...Even if I edit my answer my approach will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may create additional function `ageComparer` for convenience

```
const ageComparer = (ageRange, age) => (ageRange === '23-26' ? (age >= 23 && age <= 26) : age >=27)
```

And then utilize it during filtering

```
// ageFilter will be taken from drom down
const ageFilter = ['23-26'];

person.filter(p => p.hobby.some(v=> filterHobby.indexOf(v) !== -1) && ageFilter.some(a => ageComparer(a, +p.age)))
```

Comment: the `ageFilter` can be multiple (array)

Comment: Sure! Updated the answer for `ageFilter` to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

For search person by its age, you can make an array of a selected age like this.

`let ages = ['23','24','25'];`

code like this

```
persons.filter(item=> {return ages.indexOf(item.age)!== -1 })
```

this return person array which are matches in ages array

output:

```
[
  { name: 'Beck', age: '25', hobby: [ 'Drinking', 'Cycling' ] },
  { name: 'Candace', age: '24', hobby: [ 'Reading', 'Singing' ] }
]
```